# Is there a simple command to hide or display an imageview?

Tags: android

I have a series of imageviews that I want to display, but on a button press there needs to be less or more.  These imageviews are stored in a list.  Is there a simple way to hide or display them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`setVisibility`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility(int)) on your `ImageView`s is probably the easiest way.